# firebase forgot password usage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Hi I'm starting to become a regular on here but if any can help me with the following.  I want to test to see if a user is using a reset password and have the following:

```
if FIREBASE_REF.authData.providerData["isTemporaryPassword"] == true {
// run some code                
    }
```

but xcode is saying expression expected, if anyone knows the correct syntax I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: `expression expected` means that Xcode doesn't understand the syntax of your code. Usually if it doesn't come from a typo or a programmer syntax error, it is because you're using code from a different Swift version. Either update Xcode or use a syntax compatible with your current version.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I think it needs to be an object not a string. I'll figure it out, but gotta go to work now, I was just hoping to get it doe before I went, but I'll look at it tomorrow.  I did have a / on the line above which probably could of been the syntax error but the code still doesn't work (I think because I'm putting it in as a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have now got it sort and the solution is as follows for anyone else who is struggling with this:

```
let handle = FIREBASE_REF.authData.providerData["isTemporaryPassword"] as? Bool

            if  (handle == true) {

            // run code here.

            }
```

Comment: Why not `if FIREBASE_REF.authData.providerData["isTemporaryPassword"] as! Bool == true`?

Comment: I will give that a try.  I'm still fairly new to ios and swift and it's been about 20 years since I last did small programs in delphi, so I'm just getting used to writing software again (everything has changed so much, internet and all that), thats why I sometimes ask even noob questions.  My brain still getting into gear,lol.